# Input Number component not working after primefaces 8 upgrade

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions

Upgraded application from primefaces 5.3.6 to 8 version.According to migration guide as inputNumber component migrated from PrimeFaces Extensions to PrimeFaces.I have changed following code in xhtml:

XHTML:

```
<pe:inputNumber id="inputNumber1" decimalPlaces="0" maxValue="100" value="#{value1}">
<p:ajax update="inputNumber1" />
</pe:inputNumber>
```

to

```
<p:inputNumber id="inputNumber1" decimalPlaces="0" maxValue="100" value="#{value1}">
<p:ajax update="inputNumber1" />
</p:inputNumber>
```

After page loads getting error in developer tool console
SCRIPT5007: Invalid operand to 'in': Object expected
inputnumber.js.xhtml (14,17905)

Getting below error also as I tried to enter value 24 in inputNumber component
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'getNumericString' of undefined or null reference
inputnumber.js.xhtml (109,2133)

Comment: when you upgraded to PF8 did you also update to PF Extensions 8.0.4  I think you have a collision of old and new going on.

Comment: @Melloware yes added primefaces extension 8.0 for primefaces 8.0

Comment: Check your WAR /lib folder and make sure you don't have multiple PF jars etc. I really feel like you have a conflict with an old PF JAR and the new one.

Comment: @Melloware Its proper.Confirmed in 3 places.1 in weblogic console.Using primefaces 8.0 and extension 8.0.Second as you said WAR/lib.Third in DOM Explorer tab using developer tool console.

Comment: @Melloware Looks to me issue is with document mode.Its working fine in IE11 .Not in IE9 or IE10 document mode?why?Your inputnumber.js wont support IE9 or IE10 documnet mode then

Comment: PrimeFaces 8 dropped support for IE9/10 it only supports IE11 right now and even then not fully.  IE9/10 are riddled with security flaws and don't support enough Javascript function that modern components need.